# How to intiate Human handover in MS Teams bot using Microsoft bot framework in python

Tags: python, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have a FAQ-based bot developed in python and in some scenarios, I need route requests to live agents but I am not able to find any resource to handoff chat to live agents using python.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post the code where you've tried the handoff and it's not working?

Comment: Hi @Arpit Gupta, are you getting any error, could you please share the code with error details ?

Comment: was looking this document --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-pattern-handoff-human?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

whole tutorial is in c# and not able to find any resource regarding python. Does python bot framework sdk do support handoff library?

Answer (score 0):

currently we don't have any samples / code snips to initiate Human handover in MS Teams bot using Microsoft bot framework in python. Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/).